# In binary search what is the case we roundup the mid

Tags: search, binary

When low=mid then we change m=l+(h-l+1)/2 .My doubt is why we take low=mid.

Comment: what do you mean by roundup the mid ?

Comment: you have to get a round number as it represents an index in the array, you can roundown

Comment: See the value of mid clearly murasing

Comment: Incomplete and probably incorrect. Post complete (pseudo) code to make your point.

Comment: My doubt is why we equate low to mid

Comment: My doubt is whether we ever do.

Comment: Low equal to mid means I am including mid in search space

Comment: No, `Low == Mid` implies  `Mid >= High` and you're done. Again, write up a complete algorithm. This depends on the exact steps, 0/1 origin and inclusive/exclusive upperbound, etc

Answer (score 0):

if you mean the case when `l+h` is odd number it will be rounded automatically, you don't need any explicit code to round the `mid`.and here is binary search alorithm.

Given an array A of n elements with values or records A0 ... An−1, sorted such that A0 ≤ ... ≤ An−1, and target value T, the following subroutine uses binary search to find the index of T in A.[7]

```
Set L to 0 and R to n − 1.
If L > R, the search terminates as unsuccessful.
Set m (the position of the middle element) to the floor (the largest previous integer) of (L + R) / 2.
If Am < T, set L to m + 1 and go to step 2.
If Am > T, set R to m – 1 and go to step 2.
Now Am = T, the search is done; return m.
```

you will never find something  like `m=l+(h-l+1)/2`

Comment: `(L+R)/2` runs the risk of overflow.

Comment: You didn't get it I will paste the code then it will be clear